# pass a date value as a variable to a python script and use it inside a python script file

Tags: python, batch-file, ssis

I have a `SSIS` Package, where through execute process task I am supposed to execute a `python` script file which downloads a file with concatenated date value passed by my `ssis` package.

Now my actual question is how do I pass the date value when I am executing the `python` script from a `windows` batch file, so that I am supposed to have some code inside my `python` script to fetch that value and do the things in a simpler way, my requirement is like below:

Existing Windows Batch File content :

```
python C:\MyPythonScript.py
```

Expected Windows Batch File Content:

```
python C:\MyPythonScript.py '@DateVariable'
```

The `@DateVariable` value is dynamic and runtime value passed to batch file from my `ssis` package.

My Python Code should be like this:

```
datevalue=getDateValue from @DateVariable
#do some processing with the assigned datevalue
```

Since I am from `SQL` background I am just expecting a simple mechanism like stored procedure where parameters supplied are utilized inside the stored procedure...

Please help me with the exact code inside `python`, instead of suggesting me links to refer.

Comment: Why are you using a batch file to launch the python script?  Can't your SSIS package directly execute the python script?  If not, how is your SSIS package executing the batch file?

Comment: I have a execute process task in SSIS where i can execute a batch file by passing value to the batch file, where inturn the batch file will have a run command prompt statement to execute the python script. all i want is the value should flow from my ssis package to python script and get the work done for me

Comment: Just about all scripting languages I know have an ability to read the arguments you pass to the script.  If you execute a batch file like this: `myscript.bat passedvar`, then you can reference that passed argument in the batch file with `%1`.  If you pass two arguments then the the second is `%2`.  But since I don't know how your SSIS package is executing the batch file and trying to pass your variable to it, I really can't say if that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined my batch file as

```
echo As of %1 > C:\ssisdata\so_46734971.txt
```

The important thing to note is that windows batch file will use a 1 based, position ordinal system for parameters. If you have the python calls within the batch script, the syntax will be the same. `python MyFile.py %1`

I then configure my Execute Process Task to use two variables - The first defines where the batch file is because I'm lazy and already have that written. The second variable is a string that computes the date in yyyy-mm-dd fashion. If you need a different value, modify the expression until it matches the format your python script is expecting.

### Biml

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, is the easiest way to get reproducible SSIS packages. Here, I've defined an SSIS package that has the aforementioned variables and an Execute Process task. Simply install the free tool [BimlExpress](http://varigence.com/bimlexpress) and add a new .biml file to your project. Right click and select Generate SSIS packages and out comes a fully working reproduction.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO_46734971">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="ExecutionDateString" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">"\"" + (DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(@[System::StartTime]) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[System::StartTime]),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[System::StartTime]),2) + "\""</Variable>
                <Variable Name="Command" DataType="String">C:\ssisdata\so_46734971.bat</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteProcess 
                    Name="EP Run batch file" 
                    Executable="C:\ssisdata\so_46734971.bat"
                    Arguments="Overridden">
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression ExternalProperty="Executable">@[User::Command]</Expression>
                        <Expression ExternalProperty="Arguments">@[User::ExecutionDateString]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                </ExecuteProcess>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why they couldn't execute python directly instead of putting it in a batch file?

Comment: @Squashman It's been my experience with the Execute Process task that things can get ugly if you multiple arguments that need to be quoted. Sometimes, I've been able to mitigate that with letting a batch file deal with quoting values. But for this case, I would think the batch file is overkill

Comment: Hi Squashman, There is no way no can execute a python script directly from SSIS, if it a C# or VB Code you can execute directly..